# questions on singularities in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Which of the following sentences are true?

(a) If $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ except for a finite number of poles, then the number poles and zeros (counted according to multiplicity)are equal.
(b) If $f$ is non-constant and analytic at $z_0$ , then $f^{(n)}(z_0) \ne 0$ for some $n\ge 1$.
(c)Suppose $f$ has an essential singularity at $z=a$ and $g$ has a pole at $z=a$. Then the product $fg$ is analytic at $a$

---

I have stuck on these problem. Can I get some help?

Comment: Do you have any ideas at all? And is $C_\infty$ the Riemann sphere? (I am not used to that particular notation.) Should question (b) read … for *all* $n\ge1$, or for *some* $n\ge1$?

Comment: Is this your homework? some general rules for getting better answers: 1) Show what you have done, 2) Write only one question in each topic.

Comment: I have corrected now.I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(a) The class of functions without any essential singularities, including at infinity, is well known. Do *you* know it?

(b) Taylor series.

(c) $f=(fg)/g$.